# how to convert string from known encoding to utf-8 on the fly in python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I know about codecs library, but I don't want to write string to file.

Is there a way to hold resulting string in variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you have a string `s` encode in `encoding`.  To get the same string in `UTF-8`, you can use

```
s.decode(encoding).encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks!! I don't know why, but this method didn't work for me and after I rewrite it, all works fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ascii encoded file,f:

1)f1=unicode(f)
2)f2=f1.encode('utf-8')

I this way, you get rid of errors like:"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)"